# contract.events

Tags: solidity, javascript, events

I am listening on an event that's happening on smart contract.
`event UpdatedMaxNumber(address indexed player, uint maxNumber, uint256 timestamp);`
My original code works fine and updates the new number in the UI:

```
contract.events.UpdatedMaxNumber()
 .on('data', function(event) { //switching 'data' for 'message' does not work
  console.log('Updated max number event fired', event);
  let s = "Updated max number: " + event.returnValues[1];
  document.getElementById("viewNumber").innerHTML = s;
}).on('error', console.error);
```

Then in the console I got: `MetaMask: The event 'data' is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use 'message' instead. For more information, see:` https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193#message
That page suggests `Provider.on('message', listener: (message: ProviderMessage) => void): Provider;`

I then tried the following code:

```
web3.currentProvider.on('message', (message) => {
      console.log("message:", message);
  }).on('error', console.error);
```

This is the log and there is no maxNumber:

```
{
    "type": "eth_subscription",
    "data": {
        "subscription": "0x6e4d8735d0389c5a02b16bb6354bc126",
        "result": {
            "hash": "0xb1cf7e86d6d3d55bc0f5dc9caaad6c176b8634e6c6d4ad75e734137952faad93",
            "parentHash": "0x5cd1a79601986e49adfe02e06a4f1c8bf5056b6ac2c70417ba357c1ce3f7b5fa",
            "sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
            "miner": "0x9b7E335088762aD8061C04D08C37902ABC8ACb87",
            "stateRoot": "0xc5afd4c85cac9b747f8a49d03a724730728c0c335c12fad22fbe7cd1ddd69eef",
            "transactionsRoot": "0xc11074beeea3711f9854ee2bad2fd22def890a90a5ef7508b8c75f564978a414",
            "receiptsRoot": "0xac7e11ac98eb5e723aa0fb697ed9b86e5a66e387400acdc3dbb69ddf74375e20",
            "logsBloom": "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",
            "difficulty": "0",
            "number": 5596480,
            "gasLimit": 30000000,
            "gasUsed": 13809799,
            "nonce": "0x0000000000000000",
            "mixHash": "0x8a650b6f8b2d3a497476bf78bec86dc2ef7255ce1b4d456e490bf3da5e315e4a",
            "timestamp": 1711858404,
            "extraData": "0xd883010d0b846765746888676f312e32312e36856c696e7578"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the question, how can I use the "event message" and still get the last updated maxNumber?
Working code can be seen https://guess-number-q57u.onrender.com/

Comment: Which version of `web3.js` you're using ?

Comment: v 1.3.0 from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.3.0/dist/web3.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Your `log` output seems to be correct. You might need to parse or decode it, like:

```js
const parsedLog = contractInterface.parseLog(log)
```

---

To get the details regarding a particular event being triggered corresponding to a transaction with respect to a contract function call, the following code can be used:

1. Using **ethers.js** `v6.11.1` (i.e., the latest available version at this point in time):

```js
const { ethers } = require('ethers')

const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("YOUR_JSON_RPC_URL")

const privateKey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"

const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider)

const contractAddress = "YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS"

const contractAbi = [
    /* YOUR_CONTRACT_ABI */
]

const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, signer)

contract.functionName(arg1, arg2, ...).then((tx) => {

    tx.wait().then(async (txReceipt) => {

        const contractInterface = ethers.Interface.from(contractAbi)

        txReceipt.logs.forEach(log => {
            const parsedLog = contractInterface.parseLog(log)
            if (parsedLog) {
                if (parsedLog.name == 'YourEventName') {
                    console.log(parsedLog.args)
                }
            }
        });
    })
})
```

2. Using **web3.js** `v4.7.0` (i.e., the latest available version at this point in time):

```js
const { Web3 } = require('web3')

const web3 = new Web3("YOUR_JSON_RPC_URL")

const privateKey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"

const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);

const contractAddress = "YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS"

const contractAbi = [
    /* YOUR_CONTRACT_ABI */
]

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress)

const encodedData = contract.methods.functionName(arg1, arg2, ...).encodeABI();

// Get current gas price
web3.eth.getGasPrice()
    .then(async (gasPrice) => {
        // Estimate gas limit
        web3.eth.estimateGas({
            to: contractAddress,
            data: encodedData,
            nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(signer.address),

        }).then(async (gasLimit) => {

            const txObject = {
                to: contractAddress,
                from: signer.address,
                data: encodedData,
                gas: gasLimit,
                gasPrice: gasPrice,
                nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(signer.address),
            };

            signer.signTransaction(txObject).then(async (signedTx) => {

                const txReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);

                txReceipt.logs.forEach(log => {

                    if (log.address == contractAddress.toLowerCase()) {

                        const decodedLog = web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(
                            contractAbi.find(e => e.type === 'event' && e.name == 'YourEventName').inputs,
                            log.data,
                            log.topics.slice(1)
                        );
                        console.log("YourEventName Event: ", decodedLog);

                    }
                })
            })
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I will close this question since I used an old example using v 1.3.0, not knowing that there is a current version 4.7.0.